# vue @/src/assets/images/1.jpg: hasn't been transpiled yet error

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, loops, require

**I'm getting this error - vue @/src/assets/images/1.jpg: hasn't been transpiled yet error. I'm looping through tha App component static array. The src is specified correctly though. Using require vue method.

https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-grass-j1usw8?file=/src/components/v-carousel-item.vue
**

```js
// APP

<template>
  <v-carousel :carousel_data="sliderItems" />
</template>
<script>
import vCarousel from "./components/v-carousel.vue";
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      sliderItems: [
        { id: 1, name: "img1", img: "1.jpg" },
        { id: 2, name: "img2", img: "2.jpg" },
        { id: 3, name: "img3", img: "3.jpg" },
      ],
    };
  },
  components: {
    vCarousel,
  },
};
</script>

// Parent

<template>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="v-carousel">
      <v-carousel-item
        v-for="item in carousel_data"
        :key="item.id"
        :item_data="item"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import vCarouselItem from "./v-carousel-item.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    vCarouselItem,
  },
  props: {
    carousel_data: {
      type: Array,
      default: () => [],
    },
  },
};
</script>


// Child 

<template>
  <div class="v-carousel-item">
    <img :src="require(`../assets/images/` + item_data.img)" alt="" />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    item_data: {
      type: Object,
      default: () => {},
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to require the images upfront.

```
export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      sliderItems: [
        { id: 1, name: "img1", img: require("@/assets/images/1.jpg") },
        { id: 2, name: "img2", img: require("@/assets/images/2.jpg") },
        { id: 3, name: "img3", img: require("@/assets/images/3.jpg") },
      ],
    };
  },
```

Then update the carousel item component.

```
  <div class="v-carousel-item">
    <img :src="item_data.img" alt="" />
  </div>
```

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/little-bush-ino5zc?file=/src/components/v-carousel-item.vue:11-91

Comment: Thank you kind, but now it seems to ba an errer -'require' is not defined. in the App component

Comment: @AlexanderFilippovich that looks like an issue with codesandbox, when you go into the babel config it shows module as not being defined also!